# Linked and related questions show same question with different score

Tags: bug, related-questions, linked-questions

From [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59582/how-did-dumbledore-or-anyone-know-lily-had-sacrificed-herself-for-harry):

[image: screencap of bug - shows a question with +23 in Linked and +26 in Related]

It's been stated that it's not a bug for the same question to appear in both lists. But shouldn't they have the same score?

For the record, it doesn't look like an issue with one being the question score and the other being the answer score, because at the time of this screenshot the question was +26 and the highest-scored answer was +22 (while the screenshot shows +26 and +23).

Comment: Yay for caching!

Comment: The "Linked" section is probably cached more heavily, once a day. The question got +3 in the last 20 hours, I'm quite sure within few hours it will also show 26. :)